# Boot from USB in a COMPAQ Presario B1800

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation

I just bought a second hand laptop, COMPAQ Presario B1800. Currently, it runs Windows XP and I want to install Ubuntu. I have what I need on my USB but when I go to my BIOS menu, I can not see the usb drive. I've seen other posts that said, I need to select fast install, but I just dont see this option on my BIOS menu.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop is too old, and doesn't include an option to boot from the USB. There are alternatives that you can use to do this:

- Burn a CD/DVD. There is already several guides about how to do this.
- Use the Plop boot manager. http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/mbrinstall.html#wininst
- Install GRUB2DOS (**this is not recomended** due the lack of documentation)
- Install from the network

So, lets use Plop:

1. Download the current boot manager plpbt-5.0.14.zip.
2. Extract the zip file. Open the folder Windows.
3. You will find the batch program InstallToMBR. **Run it as administrator in VISTA/WIN7** (right mouse click on the file and choose "Run as administrator").
4. The batch creates an entry in your windows boot menu called "Install the Plop Boot Manager to the MBR".
5. Reboot and select the "Install the Plop Boot Manager to the MBR", reboot again.
6. Once this is done, you will have a menu similar to the above image, as you can read the last option is USB. Select it and follow the in-screen instructions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling "Legacy USB" and "Multiboot" or similar in the BIOS.

Make sure the USB stick is formatted in FAT16 (not FAT32). Put Ubuntu on it. Plug the USB stick in before booting and then access BIOS and see if the USB stick is there now.